# Real time video processing in raspberry pi 2

Tags: pi-3, raspicam, robotics

Hi i am planning to do real time image processing using opencv python for a differential drive bot using raspberry pi 3 B, what are the factors do we need to consider(like video stabilization, etc...) and please give a series of steps(flowchart) to follow from acquiring data to motor control(just flow charts).

Thanks in Advance